# CSR Signing simulation

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority

Tried a lot get my test csr signed from root CA(trial versions option), somehow i am not getting it dues to some of their internal check. Few questions that cropped up

1. Can i somehow signed that myself ?(its only for learning purpose)
2. any CA who can sign it on trial basis(which worked for some one)

went through many posts/blogs but couldn't find the answers

[post1](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15887/ssl-certificate-signing-by-a-ca)
[post2](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82444/clarification-needed-on-csr-signing-process)

**UPDATE on next Question**

While downloading the certificate, it popped up saying "creating a private key” with passphrase.
    1. Why it’s asking to create a private key? What is its use? (say PK1)
    2. While creating the CSR, i already had the private key (SAY PK2). Are PK1 and PK2 same?
    3. Someone from CA can also get it, like i did, so how it’s not vulnerable to attack?

I completed the wizard, and downloaded the certificate with PK1.

I referred all the possible below links but not getting above answers.

[post3](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15887/ssl-certificate-signing-by-a-ca)
[post4](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82444/clarification-needed-on-csr-signing-process)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Trial certs**
There are several CAs that will generate short-lived trial certificates for you.
Here's one:
https://www.instantssl.com/free-ssl-certificate.html

**Short certs**
And there are some CAs that will generate longer lived free certificates for you.
StartCOM/StartSSL has been doing this for several years.

https://www.startssl.com/
StartCom on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StartCom)
[Instructions on DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-with-a-free-signed-ssl-certificate-on-a-vps)

**Own CA**
There are several tutorials online about how to roll your own CA with OpenSSL.

- DataCenterOverlords.com: [Creating Your Own SSL Certificate Authority (and Dumping Self Signed Certs)](http://datacenteroverlords.com/2012/03/01/creating-your-own-ssl-certificate-authority/) (Archived [here](https://archive.today/sy0IY).)
- TLDP.org: [http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SSL-Certificates-HOWTO/c118.html] (SSL Certificates HOWTO)

I prefer Ivan Ristic's booklet: ["OpenSSL cookbook"](https://www.feistyduck.com/library/openssl-cookbook/online/ch-openssl.html). (Subsection called "Creating a Private Certification Authority" (Bottom third of page.)

Comment: I tried with https://www.startssl.com/. I got the certificate signed from them leading to next set of questions 

I am editing my original question to add up new doubts/queries

Comment: Could you put it in a new question, please? (There's a sort of "One question per question" rule/guideline.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenSSL to generate your own personal certificate authority that you can use for testing purposes.

Here is one example:
http://www.dylanbeattie.net/docs/openssl_iis_ssl_howto.html